# Is there a design pattern for "debouncing" many requests to the 'same' promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

So I have a service exposed to multiple angular controllers. This service checks if our access token is valid, and if it isn't, makes a request to the server to get a new access token (by sending a refresh token).

I want each controller to check if our token is valid and only make a single server call within a period of time if it is invalid. Since this is asynchronous, any number of controllers may call this function simultaneously (say, after a user navigates to a new route, 5 new controllers may initialize). We can't guarantee validity of a token variable in the model because the first request may be in flight already, and we don't know if the variable's state is pre or post flight (we can't just store the state and think it's kosher).

The way I might "debounce" this would be to store the promise reference in my model, then if it exists, return the model's promise instead of a new one. Then I don't make the first request until the 'debounce period' is over.

So, I'm wondering if there's a more 'Q'ey way to do this? Is this an anti-pattern? Is this perfectly adequate?

```
  // in the model/service

  var model = {
    queuedPromise:null,  
    getCurrentUser: function(){

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      if( model.queuedPromise )
      {
        return model.queuedPromise;
      }

      // let's debounce and only call the functions after 100 ms have elapsed since the first call
      setTimeout( function() {
        deferred.resolve(  model.checkRefreshToken().then(function () {
            model.getUserData().then(function () {
              model.queuedPromise = null;
            });
          })
        );

      }, 100 );

      // Many controllers may call this at once async, so store the first promise reference and return that for all subsequent calls.
      model.queuedPromise = deferred.promise;
      return deferred.promise;
    }
 };
 //...
 return model;
```

Comment: By only reading the title: "Yes, it's called a promise that is too broad"

Comment: I'm not asking about promise design patterns, i'm asking about a PARTICULAR design pattern for a specific use-case. You may want to actually read deeper than the headline before you assume you know the contents.

Comment: looks perfectly adequate to me. There's probably other ways to do it, but, the way you're doing it is pretty straight forward and easy to use.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think I needed to clearTimeout since nothing after `if(model.queuedPromise)` gets called until the last promise resolves. Nevermind, looks like you retracted =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bug in the original code, and here's the solution. The key with the "pattern" here is that you have to wait until the promise returns to nullify it (for the next page reload/time this function is needed).

```
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          if( model.queuedPromise )
          {
            return model.queuedPromise;
          }

          setTimeout( function() {
             model.checkRefreshToken().then(function () {
                model.getUserData().then(function () {

                  // only nullify after the promise handlers are invoked
                  setTimeout( function(){
                    model.queuedPromise = null;
                  }, 1 );

                  deferred.resolve({});

                });
              });

          }, 100 );


          model.queuedPromise = deferred.promise;
          return  model.queuedPromise;
```